# How to bind jVectorMap omMarkerClick to a context menu

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, markers, jvectormap

I am trying to bind a context menu to each marker created in a jVectorMap. I would like a menu to pop up whenever the user clicks a marker on the map.

I am using this context menu: http://javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/ and http://jvectormap.com/

I have tried this naive (?) approach, with no luck:

```
$(function(){
  $('#world-map').vectorMap({
      map: 'world_mill_en',

      (code omitted...)

        onMarkerClick: function(e, code){
            var cmenu = $.contextMenu.create(menu1, {theme:'vista'});
            cmenu.show(this, e);
        },
```

I think it is because I have to pass the marker being clicked to `cmenu.show()`.

Inside the onMarkerClick handler therefore, I would like to get a handle to the actual Marker that was clicked. How do I get that instance form the supplied `code` parameter?

I have tried to access `this.markers[code]`, but `this` does not seem to be of type `map`.

If not possible to combine the contextMenu and jVectorMap I have thought of an alternative approach with a simple dialog showing up when a marker is clicked. I am however clueless as to how I could do that...

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Ole.